# JS frontend for RESTful backend vs authorization

Tags: appsec, web-application, tls, authorization

I'm building web-app. And i have concern about security issues.

In world a lot of similar questions, but many of them does not have really clear answer(advise,suggestion). This is the reason why i made this question.

I have login page with username and password. User will POST them by HTTPS.
Server will compare it with username and password from DB and if everything is ok, will generate `access_token` using some specific approach like: `sha1(username + password + expiration_date)`, btw, `expiration_date` it's Unix time of expiration that token. In result `expiration_date` and `access_token` will be written into DB to related User record, `access_token` will be sent to client JavaScript app by HTTPS certainly.

Then all requests from client app will be made by HTTPS and access_token will be included into each header request. Server side should authorize this request, and detect User ID who had sent this request. Server will make search in DB by `access_token` and will check `expiration_date`). After access_token will be founded  need to check next condition: `current_date <= expiration_date`, if true then ok, if false then we need to regenerate access_token using new expiration_date and save them to DB and send new `access_token` to client?

if Yes then what do you think about that approach form security side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you at least hash+salt the password of your users in the database, your workflow seems correct.

**But** I'd like to add two things :

1. **DON'T PUT THE USER'S PASSWORD IN THE TOKEN**, it's not secure at all and totally useless. The `expiration_date` is also useless here. Just put a `sha1(username + 'randomly generated string')` and you will be good.
2. If the `expiration_date` has expired, you shouldn't auto reauth the user, but ask her to log in again. Because if you do as you say, why use a `expiration_date` then?

For my #1, since your token is sha1(username+password+expiration_date), as an attacker, I can know the username, the expiration_date and the access_token, results of the sha1.

I only have to build a local brute force system that will try all the combination of the password possible, and compare sha1(username + "current testing password" + expiration_date) to the given `access_token`, and once I find it, I'll know the password :/

Comment: and where is the third one ? you said you'd like to add three things :) Now about topic: point#1. This `randomly generated string` it should be regenerated every time after success login for each new session ? about #2 agreed. but it's not good for end users :( i need some possibility to prolongate their session.

Comment: Oups, yeah sorry, the #1 contains two things (the password and the `expiration_date`, that I first splitted in two). The randomly generated string must be regenerated every time you create a new token, aka every successful login! Imagine it's a function `generate_token(username)` that will return the token, using the sha1(username + random string) technique. Now, for the #2, you can't prolongate their session, but you can extend the duration of the session

Comment: what difference do you see between prolongate session and extend duration of the session ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't clear. In your question, you wanted to update the expiry date in case the token is valid but the expire is old. This is not good because if I finally crack your token, I will be able to connect to an old session. Now what I suggest is to extend the expiry from, say, 2h to 1day.

Comment: now I see, so "window" to crack it become narrow to one day ? let's resume it: to generate token better to use sha1(username + random::generateString()), and save result in DB. When request will come need to find the same access_token in DB and check expire date. If token expired redirect to login page. And all connection should be done by HTTPS. am I right ?

Comment: It's better, yeah :). By the way, adding the username in the sha1 is a possibility, but not required. All you need in the result is a unique token that can't be guessed.